# Set margin-top in jquery relative to the button just clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I am designing a custom pop up and i want to top margin of this div to match the top/margin-top of the button i just clicked on to bring it up.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>other content</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-menu">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class=action-menu>
    /*content*/
</div>
```

this is where i am at with my jquery, but not sure how to say top = this(the button clicked).

```
 $('.dropdown-menu').click(function() {
              $('.action-menu').show();
              //$('.action-menu').css( "top", "")    <<<<<<<<<< top margin to be the top of the button pushed
   });
```

Comment: Whoever voted to close - *too broad*?  Really?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at jQuery's [offset method](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).  Then, something like:

```
$('.action-menu').css('margin-top', $(this).offset().top + 'px');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Madbreaks, I copy and pasted this in but now the popup doesnt show at all...

Comment: It looks to me like the height the button i clicked is the same height from the top of the page as the action-menu is now from the button clicked... so i think i will need to then minus this height from the equation also??? Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to use margin at all?

Comment: It's the only way i knew of to get my pop up in a certain location in relation to whatever button in my table i clicked without creating a separate pop up for each and using normal css to set their heights. I am very new to this all so pretty bad at simplifying everything at the mo as i have just been teaching myself... @Madbreaks

Comment: Read up on CSS `position`

Comment: My div is already set to position:absolute so that it is overtop of my other elements? and as it is comes after my table without margining the div just sits underneath the table...

Comment: The equation you wrote above is working i just need to some how create a variable to calulate the height you justs got then take that away from it so it is a negative margin but i am unsure how to do that

Comment: Create a code snippet in your question, or a jsfiddle. It's unclear to me what you're saying otherwise.